# Pycharm SSH plugin missing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm

I'm using **Pycharm community 2016.2.3** under **Ubuntu 16.04**, the following issue is present with **Pycharm 2016.1.4** as well.

I'm trying to set a remote python interpreter on an external server via SSH. The documentation from Jet Brains says that a plugin named **SSH remote run** should be present and active by default, but I cannot see it neither in the plugin list nor in the online plugin list by Jet Brains.

All the other settings regarding this thing are missing, obviously because the basic plugin is missing as well. Am I missing something too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you got **Community edition**.

If you take a look at [PyCharm Editions Comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) you will see that under *Python, Frameworks & Tools* list **Remote interpreters, remote debugging, Vagrant, Docker** only available in Professional edition

Comment: Thank you, I checked that before but I didn't find anything specific, so I assumed that remote interpreter was a common feature

Comment: @nicobonne if it answered your question, you can accept it.:)